# UE4 C++ Inventory Items mutating after time

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am new to C++ and UE4. I come from a Java background. So, please be gentle here.
I am currently trying to build a game that allows the player to pick up items (I know... completely unique idea...). The items are being stored in a TArray of custom inventory item objects. Each inventory item object represents the item properties as well as the amount of the item currently in the inventory.
So far, everything seems to be functioning as designed. When I click on a pickup Item in the game level, it puts an inventory item object in the inventory component. I have watched through breakpoints etc. and have seen that it is assigning the inventory items and counts properly.
However, after about a minute, the inventory item object in the TArray suddenly mutates and contains all garbage data (default values or even random values).
I am guessing that this is due to garbage collection or something. What I don't know is how to fix it. I have tried changing the way the inventory item is created and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Here is the declarations for the pertinent info from the InventoryComponent.h:

```
private:
    /* This is a pointer to the character that owns the inventory component */
    class APilferCharacter* OwningCharacter;

    /* These are the items that are currently in the inventory */
    class TArray<class UInventoryItem*> Items;

    class UInventoryItem* CreateInventoryItem(TSubclassOf<class UInventoryItem> InventoryItemClass);

public:
    /* 
    Adds a given number of the specified item to the inventory 
    Returns the actual number of items added (May be less than the requested amount if there is not enough space)
    */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Inventory")
        uint8 AddItem(TSubclassOf<class UInventoryItem> InventoryItemClass, uint8 count = 1);
```

Here is the code for adding the inventory item to the UInventoryComponent:

```
UInventoryComponent::UInventoryComponent()
{
    MaxArrows = 15;
    MaxPotions = 3;
    this->Items.SetNum(0);
}

UInventoryItem* UInventoryComponent::CreateInventoryItem(TSubclassOf<UInventoryItem> InventoryItemClass)
{
    UInventoryItem* InventoryItem = NewObject<UInventoryItem>(this, InventoryItemClass);
    InventoryItem->OwningInventory = this; 
    InventoryItem->World = GetWorld();
    return InventoryItem;
}

uint8 UInventoryComponent::AddItem(TSubclassOf<UInventoryItem> InventoryItemClass, uint8 count)
{
    uint8 actualAddedCount = 0;
    if (count > 0) {
        UInventoryItem* itemToAdd = CreateInventoryItem(InventoryItemClass);
        UInventoryItem* existingItem = GetItemBySubType(itemToAdd->GetInventoryItemSubType());
        uint8 MaxItemCount = GetMaxItemsByType(itemToAdd->GetInventoryItemType());
        uint8 CurrentItemCount = 0;
        if (existingItem) {
            CurrentItemCount = existingItem->GetItemCount();
        }
        uint8 availableSpace = MaxItemCount - CurrentItemCount;
        actualAddedCount = std::min(count, availableSpace);
        itemToAdd->SetItemCount(actualAddedCount);

        if (existingItem)
        {
            actualAddedCount = existingItem->Add(actualAddedCount);
        }
        else
        {
            Items.Add(itemToAdd);
        }

        if (actualAddedCount > 0) {
            // Call the delegate to update the UI
            if (OnInventoryUpdated.IsBound())
            {
                OnInventoryUpdated.Broadcast();
            }
        }
    }
    return actualAddedCount;
}
```

How do I make it so that the inventory items will last for the duration of the Component?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Vital knowledge for all C++ programmers and doubly so for those coming from managed languages: [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: That said, don't smurf around storing pointers. Store the object directly in the container where possible. Far lower memory management load, almost always faster than pointer-chasing spatially diverse (and thus cache-unfriendly) objects. The cost of occasionally inserting to, removing from, and sorting the directly-stored list will often be dwarfed by the cost of regularly iterating the list of pointer-to-objects.

Comment: If your container doesn't know how many items are actually in the container and you have to write management code to keep track, don't write the code. Use a smarter container. Unreal probably has their own optimized-for-unreal container that does this, but in plain old C++ you'd start with `std::vector` and only change to a different container after profiling shows `vector`'s simplicity is not sufficiently fast.

Comment: Thank you for all of the information above. I find it very interesting to see that (I have also seen similar information in other resources as I have researched this problem). I initially thought that perhaps was the cause of the problem. However, Unreal Engine is designed to use pointers almost exclusively. The entire framework is built around pointers and, with the exception of primitives, that is almost all that is ever used. (There is a LOT of behind the scenes magic that happens to deal with memory allocation, threads, GC, etc). So, I don't really have much of a choice.

Comment: I find it interesting that the framework is built around pointers so much when everyone seems to be saying that is not the best thing for performance. However, I think that a lot of it stems from the way the framework handles objects. So, alas, unless I bypass almost ALL of the assets that the engine provides, I am stuck using a lot of pointers (If anyone knows differently, then PLEASE let me know).

Comment: So, I don't think that it is a pointer related issue. Especially since every example or tutorial that I have seen for creating an inventory system works very similarly to what I have coded (I have a few extras in mine to deal with restricting capacity of certain item types but the basic principle is there). This is why I am so confused by the problem. Other people are storing their items as pointers in a TArray and they do not have any problems. Which is why I am thinking that it has to do with how I am instantiating them.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like garbage collection. Try putting `UPROPERTY()` specifiers before those  fields to tell Unreal's garbage collector that this has shared ownership of those objects. `private:
    /* This is a pointer to the character that owns the inventory component */
    UPROPERTY()
    class APilferCharacter* OwningCharacter;

    /* These are the items that are currently in the inventory */
    UPROPERTY()
    TArray<class UInventoryItem*> Items;`

Comment: It looked to me like a rule of three-violating accidental copy nuking the contents of `Items`, but if the system is entirely pointers, that's unlikely. Might be worth adding `UInventoryComponent(const UInventoryComponent &) = delete;` and `UInventoryComponent& operator=(const UInventoryComponent &) = delete;` to the class definition to completely disallow copying just to be sure. Compiler will let out a shriek if a copy or assignment snuck in somehow.

Comment: @user4581301 IIRC unreal compiler pipeline complains if you try that, since it inserts some of that on the coder's behalf. Might be thinking of something else though.

Comment: @Ruzihm Wouldn't be surprised if they did. It's the sort of thing I'd do. Why let the library user make a mistake if you can easily prevent it without runtime cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! So, after scouring the interwebs for a solution I came across this webpage:
https://www.programmersought.com/article/40121301538/

As I was reading through it, I came across a bit that talked about UPROPERTY() handling the GC for TArrays. I then realized that I had not added the UPROPERTY() to the TArray (I figured that it did not matter since it was a private property). So, I figured that I would add it in and see if it made a difference and VOILA! It appears to have worked!

So, by changing

```
/* These are the items that are currently in the inventory */
    class TArray<class UInventoryItem*> Items;
```

to

```
/* These are the items that are currently in the inventory */
    UPROPERTY()
    class TArray<class UInventoryItem*> Items;
```

The array seems to hold the values properly and not turn them into random values after a minute or so.

Comment: Correct, you need to add UPROPERTY specifier on (almost) any pointer to a class derived from UObject to prevent it from being garbage-collected while it's still referenced.

Comment: `OwningCharacter` is redundant if the component is part of that character. Use `GetOwner()` to retrieve it. However, if you do keep it, it also must be a UPROPERTY.